# Why did the main character in "Hand of Fate" by the Rolling Stones believe that he was going to prison?

Tags: song-lyrics, rolling-stones

In *The Hand of Fate* by The Rolling Stones, the main character gets in a gunfight with a man over his ex-wife. He killed the guy, claiming that he was just defending his girlfriend against her violent, alcoholic ex-husband. He promptly fled, believing that he would go to prison over the incident if he was caught.

> The hand of fate is on me now
>   It pick me up and knock me down
>   **I'm on the run, I'm prison bound**
>   The hand of fate is heavy now
>   I killed a man, I'm highway bound
>   The wheel of fortune keeps turning round
>   Turning round, turning round
>   I should have known it was a one horse town
>
> My sweet girl was once his wife
>   **He had papers the judge had signed**
>   The wind blew hard, it was stormy night
>   **He shot me once, but I shot him twice**
>   The hand of fate is on me now
>   It pick me up and it kicked me right down
>   Kicked me right down
>   Kicked me right down
>
> **I had to save her life**
>   Yeah, I gunned him twice
>   Yeah, and I watched him die, watch out boy
>   Yeah, I watched him die

What, exactly, are the papers that the judge had signed, and why did her ex-husband have them? Is this referring to divorce papers, or some other papers that the ex-husband had acquired?

Also, does the line that "He shot me once, but I shot him twice" imply that this was also self-defense, or was the main character the instigator here?

If the main character really was acting in self-defense and/or defense of her like he claimed, why did he think that he would go to prison over the incident?